# How to add a split ActionBar in android.I have got everything right but it still doesn't work.

Tags: android, android-actionbar

here is my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/one" android:title="oneone"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/two" android:title="twotwo"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/three" android:title="threethree"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/four" android:title="fourfour"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</menu>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sanjith.actionbartwo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This code gives me three buttons on the actionbar and one on the overflow.
I want to get all the buttons on the bottom actionbar.I have searched the internet for this but i haven't found a solution.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

```
<manifest ...>
<activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
</manifest>
```

Comment: but my minSdk is 16.so i don't have to add the meta-data tag.right ?

Comment: Also i had tried adding those 2 lines.It doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before unfortunately the action bar doesn't split by code you need to fill all the room available so the action bar would split by itself with your permission of course but there are no possible way to split it if it still have space

Comment: 'android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow' the problem is that this code doesn't split it until no space available